# SPARK AR STUDIO V 94.0.15 Can't logging the Facebook account

Tags: facebook, spark-ar-studio

I'm tried to login spark AR studio (Version 94.0.15) with my Facebook account but every time the same error occurred

> Login failed Please try again later

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HokRB.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is an error a lot of people face .
[Click here](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/630776517350110/) to read more about the problems and solutions!